# pandas: remove row where value is equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas

i want if the the result of this command is >1 item then delete row with the zero.

```
list_count = df.groupby(['id_client', 'date'])['count'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

example of result the code above

My original df should have:

```
908     01/2020     0
908     01/2020     35
907     01/2020     0
907     01/2020     37
909     01/2020     50
910     01/2020      0
```

result of the above code line

```
    908     01/2020     [0, 35] 
    907     01/2020     [0, 37]
    909     01/2020      50
    910     01/2020      0
```

**expected output**

```
908     01/2020     35
907     01/2020     37
909     01/2020     50
910     01/2020      0
```

Comment: What column would the zero occur in?

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Comment: i added my original post @eshirvana please have a look . thank you

Comment: what happens if you have another line `907     01/2020     12`?

Comment: Also you did not show the **expected** output, only the current output of your function

Comment: i added my expected output @mozway please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can compute two masks and slice:

```
# values where group has only 1 element
m1 = df.groupby(['id_client', 'date'])['count'].transform('size').eq(1)
# values ≠ 0
m2 = df['count'].ne(0)
# keep values that have either criterion
df[m1|m2]
```

output:

```
   id_client     date  count
1        908  01/2020     35
3        907  01/2020     37
4        909  01/2020     50
5        910  01/2020      0
```

Comment: thank you but i think that it should be groupby date and id_client no.?

Comment: @tamo007 sure, this depends on how you want to group (this did not make a difference in your example)

Comment: I give up waiting, your interpretation of the problem is most likely the correct one. +1